# converting Date object to TimeWithZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I need to convert a Date object into a TimeWithZone object representing the beginning of that day in a given time zone.

The following approach works, but seems too convoluted as it requires me to convert the date to a string:

```
?> date = Date.parse("2010-02-17")
=> Wed, 17 Feb 2010
>> ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].parse(date.to_s)
=> Wed, 17 Feb 2010 00:00:00 EST -05:00
>> ActiveSupport::TimeZone['UTC'].parse(date.to_s)
=> Wed, 17 Feb 2010 00:00:00 UTC 00:00
```

Is there a better way I'm missing?

Edit:
People are suggesting variations of:

```
?> date.to_datetime.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').beginning_of_day
=> Tue, 16 Feb 2010 00:00:00 EST -05:00
```

As you can see, this isn't an equivalent conversion since it leaves me at the start of Feb. 16th EST, instead of the start of Feb. 17th EST.

Comment: It looks like your solution might be the correct way to go.

Comment: I have edited my response to overcome this issue.

Comment: Give yourself the solution! =) Time with Time Zones is always messy.

Answer (score 10):

I'm late to the party, but this is still a great question.  ActiveSupport's `in_time_zone` was introduced since the O.P., but it does exactly what you want without parsing a string (slow) or setting Time.zone (risky):

```
>> date = Date.parse("2010-02-17")
=> Wed, 17 Feb 2010
>> date.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
=> Wed, 17 Feb 2010 00:00:00 EST -05:00
```

Of course if you want the beginning of day expressed at utc, you can do this:

```
>> date.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').utc
=> 2010-02-17 05:00:00 UTC
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have `Time.zone` set in Rails then you can call `Date#at_beginning_of_day` (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-at_beginning_of_day).  Contrast this with `Date#to_datetime`:

```
Time.zone
 => #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x10cf10858 @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @utc_offset=nil, @current_period=nil, @name="UTC"> 

date = Date.today
 => Thu, 31 May 2012 

date.to_datetime
 => Thu, 31 May 2012 00:00:00 +0000 

date.at_beginning_of_day
 => Thu, 31 May 2012 00:00:00 UTC +00:00 

Time.zone = 'America/Chicago'
 => "America/Chicago" 

date.to_datetime
 => Thu, 31 May 2012 00:00:00 +0000 

date.at_beginning_of_day
 => Thu, 31 May 2012 00:00:00 CDT -05:00
```

Comment: `Time.zone` **is** threadsafe, it sets the zone in `Thread.current[:time_zone]`. [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08754f12e65a9ec79633a605e986d0f1ffa4b251/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb#L39)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I removed that comment, but left this one so people don't think you're crazy ;)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend against any solution that converts the date to a time using `to_datetime` or `to_time` because those methods are unaware of the zone, and tacking `in_time_zone` onto the result, as some answers suggest, won't retroactively fix the mistake. Also, don't try to build your own daylight saving time math using UTC offsets. You're bound to get it wrong, and you're doing work unnecessarily.

**Use the TimeZone itself which has this logic built in.**

Given a zone and a date, you can get a TimeWithZone for the beginning of the day like this:

```
time = zone.local(date.year, date.month, date.day)
```

If you want a specific time of day other than the beginning, you can pass the hour, minute, and second as the 4th, 5th, and 6th arguments to `#local`.

If `zone` is actually your system's local time zone (`Time.zone`), then ActiveSupport will let you shorten the above to this:

```
time = date.to_time_in_current_zone
```

All of the above handle daylight saving time correctly. Let's verify that by looking at the UTC offsets for two times, one that's outside DST and one that's within DST:

```
irb(main):009:0> zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)']
=> (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
irb(main):010:0> t1 = zone.local(2013, 1, 1)
=> Tue, 01 Jan 2013 00:00:00 EST -05:00
irb(main):011:0> t2 = zone.local(2013, 5, 1)
=> Wed, 01 May 2013 00:00:00 EDT -04:00
irb(main):012:0> t1.utc_offset
=> -18000
irb(main):013:0> t2.utc_offset
=> -14400
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
'2010-04-01'.to_time.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)').beginning_of_day
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract utc_offset:

```
d = Date.today
Time.zone.class.all.map(&:name).map { |tz| dt = d.to_datetime.in_time_zone(tz); dt -= dt.utc_offset }
```

Using ActiveSupport::TimeZone[tz] doesn't take daylight savings time into account.

```
Time.zone.class.all.map(&:name).map { |tz| o = d.to_datetime.in_time_zone(tz).utc_offset - ActiveSupport::TimeZone[tz].utc_offset }
```