# Operations between ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone and Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting Date object to TimeWithZone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518398/converting-date-object-to-timewithzone)

Well, I'm beggining on web development with Rails (3.2.6) and currently lovin' it :D

I need some help from you. I have a `Processo` model with some fields, `prazo`as `datetime`and `created_at` as well... you know, that standard thing migrations create...

My problem is: I need to know how to do some math operation between both fields. I need to know how many days there are between `created_at` and `prazo`.

I've tried nearly everything I could search here and on Google. Can you help me ?

`prazo` has a `Date` class and `created_at` has `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` class.

Thanks a lot and sorry to be just leeching on my first posting.

Cheers!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2518798/643500

Comment: thanks for the answer D3mon-1stVFW! So, that will work converting the Date object in an ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone object? Hmm, that seems an interesting approach. I'd do the complete opposite. I'll try here and will let you know. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, re-read the question.. Try what Frederick Cheung said

> You want to say ['my_datetime_column >= ? and my_datetime_column < ?',
>   Date.today(), Date.today()+1] This works because the dbs I know of
>   handle '2007-04-20' as being '2007-04-20 00:00:00'. If you db does
>   something different you'll have to adjust for that.

You may want to double-check the timezone though

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/146579#648686